# Add padding to last Child if only 2 are present

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In a WooCommerce shop sometimes I do have 3 `<p>` and sometimes I do have 2 `<p>` (depends on the product)
How to I archive to add a padding to the last `<p>` but only if there are 2 `<p>` are shown. No padding should be added when all 3 `<p>` are shown.

```
<div class="astra-shop-thumbnail-wrap">
    <a href="#" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link"><img width="186" height="186" src="#"> </a>
        <div class="label-group">
            <a href="#" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link"></a>
                <div class="categories-link">
                    <a href="#" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="sfinkslinks">Accessoires</a>
                    <a href="#" class="sfinkslinks">Schale</a>
                </div>
        </div>

<p class="wc-gzd-additional-info tax-info">inkl. MwSt.</p>
<p class="wc-gzd-additional-info shipping-costs-info">zzgl. Versandkosten</p>
<p class="wc-gzd-additional-info delivery-time-info">Lieferzeit: 5 - 7 Werktage</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How [..] to add a padding to the **last** `<p>` *but only* if there are **2** `<p>`

A combined selector which includes both:

- `:last-of-type`
- `:nth-of-type(2)`

will select only those elements which are both **second** and **last** in the current series.

**e.g.**

```
p:nth-of-type(2):last-of-type
```

---

**Working Example:**

```css
div {
  float: left;
  width: 120px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

p {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  text-align: center;
}

p:nth-of-type(2):last-of-type {
  padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
</div>

<div>
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
</div>

<div>
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
</div>

<div>
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
<p>Paragraph 4</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `+` selector

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

.wc-gzd-additional-info {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.tax-info+.shipping-costs-info+.delivery-time-info {
  padding: 0
}

.shipping-costs-info+.delivery-time-info,
.tax-info+.delivery-time-info {
  padding: 50px
}
```

```html
<p class="wc-gzd-additional-info tax-info">inkl. MwSt.</p>
<p class="wc-gzd-additional-info shipping-costs-info">zzgl. Versandkosten</p>
<p class="wc-gzd-additional-info delivery-time-info">Lieferzeit: 5 - 7 Werktage</p>

<hr />

<p class="wc-gzd-additional-info shipping-costs-info">zzgl. Versandkosten</p>
<p class="wc-gzd-additional-info delivery-time-info">Lieferzeit: 5 - 7 Werktage</p>

<hr />

<p class="wc-gzd-additional-info tax-info">inkl. MwSt.</p>
<p class="wc-gzd-additional-info delivery-time-info">Lieferzeit: 5 - 7 Werktage</p>
```